# È corretta la frase seguente: 'I libri che ti hanno regalati ne sono molto curiosa...'?

Tags: word-usage, grammar, word-choice, articles, phrases

Mi chiedo se sia più corretta, più italiana la frase menzionata sopra oppure questa frase: 'Sono molto curiosa dei libri che ti hanno regalato'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, la prima frase non è corretta in italiano moderno, e per due motivi.

Intanto la concordanza del participio nelle proposizioni relative (“I libr**i** che ti hanno regalat**i**...”) si usava in secoli andati, ma ora è considerata desueta.

Ma, soprattutto, la costruzione con quel pronome “ne” è molto strana. Tutta la frase suona come se uno avesse cominciato con una certa idea in mente (per esempio “I libri che ti hanno regalato mi incuriosiscono”) e poi avesse cambiato idea strada facendo. Quel pronome avrebbe senso solo in un'eventuale seconda frase, come per esempio: “I libri che ti hanno regalato sono ancora incartati. Ne sono molto curiosa”.

Quindi consiglierei senz'altro la seconda formulazione.